# In Extjs 3.4, editing the field value in editable grid using Selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, extjs, extjs3

I am automating my application in java using selenium web driver. Here facing difficulty in modifying the editable field in the editable grid. The selenium says that:

> "Element cannot be cleared as the field is not editable".

I tried to find the element using xpath and clicked on it. Then the focus was seen but not able to clear and also not able to edit the field value.

Here is my field html code:

```
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-quantity1 x-grid3-dirty-cell" tabindex="0" style="width:98px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-quantity1" unselectable="on">1</div>
</td>
```